# How to apply a Pulumi Azure Function App runtime

Tags: python, azure, pulumi

I have a Pulumi script to deploy few services. Everything is fine except I don't understand how to apply a runtime to Functions App

```
api_function_app = azure.appservice.FunctionApp("ApiFunctionApp",
location=resource_group.location,
enabled= True,
enable_builtin_logging = True,
resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
app_service_plan_id=functionStoragePlan.id,
storage_account_name=functionStorageAccount.name,
storage_account_access_key=functionStorageAccount.primary_access_key, os_type="linux", version="~3")
```

Has anyone seen any example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set a value for `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` application setting

```
...
app_settings={
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
},
...
```